# Pin ImageView and headed view in the top while scrolling and make the other view as scrollable in android

Tags: java, android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I need to pin the image while scrolling with the headed section and need to scroll other thing in the screen.

Here I need the header as fixed while scrolling and the half of the fill 2 image shown while scrolling.

Now the header actionsof on click are not working after addding nestedScrollView.

Also the nested view is overlapping with the above view while scrolling

[image]

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        style="@style/CoordinatorLayout"
        android:background="red"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_app_bar"
            style="@style/Collapsing.AppBarLayout"
            android:background="blue">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_collapsing_toolbar"
                style="@style/Collapsing.CollapsingToolbarLayout"
                android:layout_height="427dp">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_x5"
                        android:background="green"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/header_view"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/back"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@drawable/black"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/back"
                
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_left"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/header_my_home"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:textSize="18dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:text="MY Home Feed"/>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:id="@+id/label"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                          >
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/label1"
                                android:layout_width="80dp"
                                android:layout_height="48dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:visibility="visible"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:textSize="18dp"
                                android:textColor="#707070"
                                android:text="label1"
                                />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                  
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@id/iv_background"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/image" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@id/fill_1"
                        android:src="@drawable/fill_1"
                        android:scaleType="fitStart"
                        android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@id/fill_2"
                        android:src="@drawable/fill_2"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:layout_marginTop="128dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />
                </FrameLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/Collapsing.Toolbar" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                style="@style/Collapsing.Divider" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/nested_scroll">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="27dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
               >

            </TextView>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
            <View style="@style/Divider.Horizontal.Gray"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_x2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_x2"
            android:layout_height="2dp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    >
                </TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="lanl">
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    >
                </TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

                <View style="@style/Divider.Horizontal.Gray"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_x2"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_x2"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"android:visibility="visible">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                  >
                </TextView>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    >

                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/search"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@color/dark_blue"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/blue_light"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />
            <com.finaonation.utility.NonScrollableViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
               
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    
                </TextView>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    >

                </ImageView>
            </LinearLayout>
                <View style="@style/Divider.Horizontal.Gray"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_x2"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_x2"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/divider"
                    android:visibility="visible"/>
            </LinearLayout>

         
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_m"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <!-- HEADER -->
            <RelativeLayout
                ...
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
                .....
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

       <!-- IF YOU WANT TO KEEP "Choose Item" always on top of the RecyclerView, put this TextView here
        <TextView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="bottom"
             android:text="choose item" />
       -->
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: It is not a choose item

Comment: The below app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" is not only a recycler view it has a textviews image views and so on. So how the AppBarLayout will shown while scrolling. My issue is when i scroll my screen to next screen, it failed to see at the end. But I can able to see the end of the screen when I add nested scrillview.